# Hide some properties in JSON response object in sails.js

Tags: json, node.js, sails.js

I'm very new to sails.js framework. I want to hide some particular fields in the response JSON object when it gets queried.

For example, I have a model object User:

```
User: {
  name: 'Paul',
  email: 'paul@gmail.com',
  token: 'sdffsdf',
  id: 1
}
```

I want hide "token" property in case if this user is queried by GET request: `localhost:1337/user?id=1`

Can somebody give me a hint how to do that?

Comment: Pass your token in the header of your http request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Overwrite the `toJSON()` function of your model. This can also be used to hide other sensitive data.

```
module.exports = {
    attributes: {
        name: 'string',
        email: 'email',
        token: 'string',
        toJSON: function() {
            var obj = this.toObject();
            delete obj.token;
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but what if you have a big collection of high resolution images? This means, it will collect all these image data and than show only name and email attribute. Better is, to collect only the attribute data we're interested in (i.e. name and email) and than send them to the output.

Comment: @AndaluZ I used [node-json-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-transform) in a project to build customized json results from server

Answer (score 2):

It used to work before sails 1.0, since that using instance methods is no longer supported. using this would result in:

> The `toJSON` instance method is no longer supported.

instead you have to use **customToJSON** as mentioned in the [docs](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson)

```
customToJSON: function () {
 return _.omit(this, ['token'])
},
```

and note that you can not use arrow function, it has to be written just like this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to omit certain fields conditionally in your controller for example, you can do as following:

```
    self.findByRerence = async function (req, res) {
    var book = await Pot.findOne();

    if (req.user.id === 1) {
          book = _.omit(book, ['reference']);
        }
    res.ok(book);
    }
```

In this example, I remove the reference of the book only if it's the user that has the ID number 1 that is making this request.

Of course this is just to showcase how to do it.